# Coinbase API call to get crypto spot prices

Tags: coinbase-api

Just started exploring CoinBase APIs.
I found that

- there is a new set of APIs under the umbrella of Coinbase Cloud: https://www.coinbase.com/cloud
- there is an older(legacy?) set of APIs known as Coinbase Digital API: https://developers.coinbase.com/

I need to programmatically fetch current spot price for certain cryptocurrencies, I found an endpoint for this in the old API:  https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/
Is this the correct API call to get the prices?
Is there an equivalent endpoint in one of the new Coinbase Cloud APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the spot price api

https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/api-prices#get-spot-price

example: https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/BTC-USD/spot

or you can use the ticker api (I think this is the better option)

https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/exchange/reference/exchangerestapi_getproductticker

example: https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/ticker

Comment: Thanks, that helps! Just curious, why do you think that the ticker api is a better option?

Comment: @snovo because it has more data so if i ever want any of that I don't have to change the api call and somewhat future proofs the code. along with price it includes the trade_id, size, time, bid, ask and volume.